# Creating a Cocoapod: CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I have created a pod. It is here: https://cocoapods.org/pods/FlexColorPicker. Here is [the podspec file](https://github.com/RastislavMirek/FlexColorPicker/blob/master/FlexColorPicker.podspec).

The problem is that I cannot install it with `pod install`. When runing it I get this:

```
CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "FlexColorPicker":
In Podfile:
  FlexColorPicker
Specs satisfying the `FlexColorPicker` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.
```

However, the pod supports iOS 10.0 or higher ([see podspec](https://github.com/RastislavMirek/FlexColorPicker/blob/master/FlexColorPicker.podspec)) and the project I am trying to include it in has deployment target 10.2. Where is the problem??

Second issue is thatCocoapods website does not seems to index my pod... It does not appear in seach results even for it's own name. You can try to search for *FlexColorPicker* [here](https://cocoapods.org) to see for yourself.

*Any* help is *very* appreciated.

Comment: To make it even more strange, `pod try FlexColorPicker` works just fine... But `pod install` just will not install it.

Answer (score 4):

My bad. I did not notice that I had `platform :ios, '9.0'` in the podfile of the project that I am adding my pod to.

The second issue persists however.

Comment: Thanks buddy! After changing version from "platform :ios, '9.0'" to "platform :ios, '10.0'" solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Since you already figured out the first issue, I'll only address the second one.

How long has it been since you created and pushed the pod?  It will take a while for it to show up in the search results, and thats normal.  Give it a day for the first version.  It will be much faster after that.

Comment: I pushed it yesterday... Ok, I hope it is just taking a bit longer then usuall. I will wait 2 more days.

Comment: There's also an issue with your docset: http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/FlexColorPicker/1.0.6   Click on documentation link on your cocoapod page